# Word *Fallen* is an Adjective or Verb?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, past-participles

Is the construction of sentence a) is correct?

> a) This tree was fallen on my bike.

As per my understanding above sentence is incorrect because **fallen** is an **intransitive** verb. And the sentence should be

> b) This tree fallen on my bike. (Simple past, Statative)

Or

> c) This tree had fallen on my bike. (Past perfect)

But if I want to tell someone the status of tree, can I say as below?

> d) This was the tree which fallen on my bike.

Or

Should I simply say?

> e) This was the tree which felled on my bike. (Simple past)

Also, it could be passive voice if I use an agent

> f) This tree was fallen on my bike by wind. (passive voice)

Comment: This tree had fallen on my bike. This tree fell on bike. This was the tree that fell on my bike. or This was the tree that had fallen on my bike. This tree was felled by the wind onto my bike.

Comment: Simple past is "The tree fell on my bike".

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for simple past tense, which would be "fell."

"Yesterday, there was a storm and the tree fell on my bike."

Passive voice might technically be "had fallen," but this sounds very awkward, and any sentence structured this way should probably be reworded. (Usually in English you want to avoid passive voice, the major exceptions all involve a sense of helplessness, for example "he was kidnapped" or "she was hour by a car.")

Source: http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/fall.html

Answer (score -1):

> a) This tree was fallen on my bike.
>
> As per my understanding above sentence is incorrect because fallen is an intransitive verb. And the sentence should be
>
> b) This tree fallen on my bike. (Simple past, Stative)

This is also **wrong** because a verb *is essential*. Sentence (a) is actually **correct** and not (b).

Or

> c) This tree had fallen on my bike. (Past perfect)

Correct!

> But if I want to tell someone the status of tree, can I say as below?
>
> d) This was the tree which fallen on my bike.

*Wrong. It should be*

**This was the tree which had fallen on my bike.**

> Or
>
> Should I simply say?
>
> e) This was the tree which felled on my bike. (Simple past)

Wrong. It should be 'This was the tree which **fell** on my bike.'

> Also, it could be passive voice if I use an agent
>
> f) This tree was fallen on my bike by wind. (passive voice)

Wrong. It should be **This tree was felled by the wind on my bike.**

You need to read up extensively on tenses, stative verbs, intransitive verbs, and more.

Comment: a is not correct; fall is not a transitive verb and thus cannot be passive.